# Printing to an output file given in command line

Tags: c

How would you print to an output file given by the user in the command line? I know how to print to an output file, but don't know how to get the file when it is given by the user.

The file given by the user might not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read the name of the file from the input parameters.

The parameters are stored into the array `argv` of the main. Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "w" );
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it work if the file hasn't given in the command line hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Yes because when you open a file in write mode. If it doesn't exist it will be create.

Comment: can you add a quick statement print "abc" to the file. when i run my code it says the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually is impossible that this code prints: "the file doesn't exist" because there is no printf with this text.
Moreover when you open in written mode it creates the file.
Moreover I tested the code and it works.
Moreover you wrote: "I know how to print to an output file"

Comment: it didn't print that. when i tried to open the file, the file didn't exist. but i got it working, thanks for the help!